# Spotfire - Filtering a Table by Values in a Calculated Column

Tags: filtering, calculated-columns, spotfire, unique-values

I am trying to filter a table visualization of all of my data by looking to see if a Study Number contains Activity A. If a Study Number contains Activity A then I want to filter for all rows containing those Study Numbers even if the Activity is not A. See mock data below. In my real data set I have ~55,000 rows.

I have created a calculated to return Study Numbers if Activity= A but I am not sure where to go from there. Thanks for any help.

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`If(UniqueConcatenate([Activity]) OVER ([Study Number])~="A","Y","N")`

Will give you this resulting column that you can then filter on (or you can use the formula as a Data Limiting Expression:

[image]